# Serial ports - Can't read data, I just wrote

Tags: python, multithreading, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to make a simple simulation of communication between two devices via serial ports(on linux to be clear). I have came up with idea to put reading from serial port into diffrent thread, but the problem is that this thread throw me an error like this:

```
Is open?  True
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "client.py", line 18, in func
    if len(ser.readline()) > 0:
  File "/home/bartosz/PycharmProjects/socket-serial-comm/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 478, in read
    raise portNotOpenError
serial.serialutil.SerialException: Attempting to use a port that is not open
```

So it seems that port I am trying to use is not open, but when I am printing from this thread  `print("Is open? ", ser.is_open)`
 it gives me True, and I can't open the port in thread because of that.

Here's my code:

```
import serial
import threading
import time


ser = serial.Serial('/dev/pts/0', timeout=1)


def func():
    print("Is open? ", ser.is_open)
    while True:
        if len(ser.readline()) > 0:
            print(ser.readline())


x = threading.Thread(target=func, args=ser)
x.start()
time.sleep(1)
ser.write(b'some text\n')

time.sleep(1)
ser.close()
```

Any thoughts why this behave like that?

Answer (score 0):

This is working exactly as you coded it.

The process that is reading the serial port is running forever in an infinite loop with `While True:`, but the port itself is `ser.close()` about 2 seconds after the processing thread is started.
Since `ser.readline()` is executed even after `ser.close()`, the question error occurs.

Before calling `ser.close()`, you need to install a mechanism to terminate `def func():` thread processing.

By the way, the process of judging with `len(ser.readline())` in `if` statement and then `print(ser.readline())`, there is data requires input of two lines, but the first line is not displayed, it would be weird to just print the next line.

You should review the process.